# Setting a new value to an array gives different results than it should

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this array:

```
L = np.array([[5,4],[3,2]])
```

And I want to change the second bracket.

If I do:

```
print(L[1] + (-0.6)*L[0])
```

it will give me this array:

```
[0,-0.4]
```

But, if I change it like this:

```
L[1] = L[1] + (-0.6)*L[0]
print(L)
```

it prints:

```
# [[5 4] [0 0]]
```

Why are the outputs different?

Comment: What part of `L` you want to overwrite? Second row? What is the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

The first example:

```
L[1] + (-0.6)*L[0]
```

returns the result of the specified operation, but it isn't assigned so you just have the result.

In your second example

```
L[1] = L[1] + (-0.6)*L[0]
```

the result is written to `L[1]`, however the result is cast to the `dtype` of `L`. Which is an integer. So the intermediate result is simply truncated.

This "truncation" is the reason why the result isn't "correct":

```
>>> (L[1] + (-0.6)*L[0]).astype(int)  # simulating the truncation
array([0, 0])
```

Comment: It is interesting that the augmented assignment statement `L[1] += -0.6*L[0]` will fail because of a casting rule, in this case, but a regular assignment will not fail.

Comment: @wim Maybe they just forgot to add it to `=` as well or they just feel like that's explicit "casting" and therefore allowed while `[*]=` is implicit and therefore not allowed. Or it's because `=` doesn't use the ufunc-machinery (which allows to specifiy `casting=`) and therefore was simply "left" as is. But that's just guessing, maybe worth to ask about it on numpys issue tracker.

Comment: It's actually documented behaviour.  See the [warning](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#arithmetic-matrix-multiplication-and-comparison-operations) mentioned here.  Nonetheless, I find the discrepancy surprising (and questionable design choice).